# How can I dynamically modify the width and location of a button in C# from the code-behind?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a C# application, and I need to modify the width and location of a button dynamically from the code-behind (back-end) of my application.

Currently, I'm using the following code to adjust the width of the button:

```
button1.Width += 20;
```

This code successfully increases the width of the button by 20 pixels. However, I'm also looking to update the button's location based on its new width. I attempted to achieve this using the following code:

```
button1.Location = new Point(button1.Width - 20, button1.Height);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as expected. The button's location doesn't update correctly relative to its new width.

I would appreciate any suggestions or alternative approaches to dynamically modify both the width and location of the button based on its updated size. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "The button's location doesn't update correctly" - does that mean it updates _incorrectly_, eg. to a different location than you're expecting?

Comment: You write C# application, but is it WPF or winforms?

Comment: 1.updates correctly 2.winforms

Comment: you can use `button1.Left` and `button1.Top`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `button.SetBounds` to set four point x,y coordinates for button.

```
button.SetBounds(button.Location.X,button.Location.Y,button.Width,button.Height);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your question you are setting the location to be the buttons size.
ie. If your button is 200x100, it will be placed at Location (200, 100).

When moving the control relative to its current location, its x and y values need to be modified.

As mentioned by others in the comments, you can use the controls `Left` and `Top` properties to set the location.  This is especially handy in your situation where you want to move the control relative to its current position.

For example, to move the button to the left by 10, subtract 10 from `Left`.

```
button1.Left -= 10;
```

You can also set the location explicitly by setting the controls `Location`.

```
button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X - 10, button1.Location.Y);
```

If you have your button docked, location modifications will have no effect.